# Single Controller to Handle CRUD Actions for Multiple Key-Value Validation Tables, Possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, crud

I have a web application that has several drop downs that are powered by validation tables that have the same fields [ID, Key, Value, Print Value]. Is there a way I can write a single rails controller and methods to handle all the CRUD activities for these different table?

I have thought about combining all the tables together into a single table with an additional field to indicate which drop down but I am not convinced this is the best method.

Any thoughts or guidance you can give on would be very helpful. I am new to rails too so if there is a 'rails way' please point me in the right direction.

Thanks, 
Joe

Comment: You can subclass controllers, that may work.  What do you mean by validation tables?  Validations are also in Models, are you referring to something different?

Comment: My validation table in the database holds all the valid values for a field. ie. States in the United States would yield a table where there would be an entry for each state. In my app, I want to be able to manage these validation tables and I was hoping to do it without creating a model for each one.

Comment: Is it a single table?  If so, you may look into STI, if not, you may be able to subclass controllers.  Post more of your data-model and model code if you can.